# Have can i find out where is a mistake in my registration form?

Tags: python, django, validation

So, i have a problem. I've created a register form and a model User that inherites **models.Model**

```
class User(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Author'),
        (2, 'Customer'),
        (3, 'Author and Customer')
    )
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=128, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=CHOICES, default='Customer')
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='', blank=False)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=512, verbose_name='')
```

Photos of form with data and without:

[image][image]

Also i have such form:

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            'username': widgets.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-email',
            'placeholder': 'Username'
            }),
            'first_name': widgets.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-email',
                'placeholder': 'First name'
            }),
            'last_name': widgets.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-email',
                'placeholder': 'Last name'
            }),
            'patronymic': widgets.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-email',
                'placeholder': 'Patronymic'
            }),
            'age': widgets.NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-email',
                'placeholder': 'Age'
            }),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-email',
                'placeholder': 'Email'
            }),
            'role': widgets.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-select',
            }),
            'password': PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-password',
                'placeholder': 'Password'
            }),
            'about': widgets.Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-email',
                'placeholder': 'A few words about you'
            })
        }
```

And this is a view for registration

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'form': form})
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Successfull!")
```

What can be wrong?It always skips form.is_valid() (i suppose data is invalid)
P.S. I know if form is wrong it will return a response error

Comment: A bit unrelated to the problem but you appear to be making a user model for authentication? In that case this model should inherit from either `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` (Will make it much easier to deal with authentication that way). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the form is not valid, typically the form is re-rendered, and will print the errors next to the fields, so:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Successfull!")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: may be i dont understand, but it doesn't show/change anything :(

Comment: @Ihor: but id you alter the codeflow to check for a `request.method == 'POST'`, furthermore if th form is not valid you should *not* construct a new form, that is only for non-POST requests.

Comment: i'm new in django and cannot understand smth sometimes. Could you tell me what should i do?

Comment: @Ihor: just edit the view as is specified in the answer. Note that the `else` is a the same level as `request.method == 'POST'`, not `form.is_valid()`

Comment: i've done it, but it doesn't work still :(

Comment: @ihor: print `print(form.errors)` *immediately* after constructing the `RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.

Comment: oh yes, i see. The problem in SelectField. 'Select a valid choice. 2 is not one of the available choices'. I've fixed it. Thank you so much!!